# Error handling of SPARQL query with given RDF graph

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have the following RDF graph with prefixes

```
PREFIX r: <http://dbpedia.org/resources/>
PREFIX o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
```

[image: graph]

And the query

```
PREFIX r: <http://dbpedia.org/resources/>
PREFIX o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?s ?author
WHERE {
   ?s o:type o:Book .
   ?s o:author ?author .
   ?author ?incategory r:Category:American_atheists.
}
```

I am now wondering what the output would look like. I have tried using https://dbpedia.org/sparql but this results in a parsing error.
Is this a proper query anyway ?
The graph has the prefix `r` for Book and the query has `o:Book` in the triple.

Comment: And you couldn't figure out why the parsing error occurs? The prefixed form of categories doesn't work with an additional colon, i.e. `r:Category:American_atheists.` is invalid. Either you use the full URI `<http://dbpedia.org/resources/Category:American_atheists>` you use an additional prefix for the categories, usually it's `PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resources/Category:>` and then write `dbc:American_atheists`

Comment: The screenshot is from a textbook, yes? So if this is some kind of exercise, the wrong prefix of book is either a typo or part of the exercise to demonstrate how important using the correct prefix is.

Comment: Please consider changing the title of your question. All questions tagged #SPARQL could be generalised with the current title.

Comment: Besides the syntax error with the prefix, you have two other issues that cause the empty query. 1) it must be `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` 2) it must be `rdf:type`

Comment: Thank you very much @AKSW. Is it necessary to define the `PREFIX rdf` then as well besides `r` and `o` ?

Comment: For correctness, yes. Or you can use the Turtle shortcut `a`, i.e. `?s a o:Book .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parsing error is due to the colon after `r:Category`. Colon in abbreviated IRIs can only be used as part of the prefix. This query should work:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX r: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?s ?author
WHERE {
  ?s rdf:type o:Book .
  ?s o:author ?author .
  ?author ?incategory <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:American_atheists> .
}
```

Or, if you want a more concise `WHERE` clause:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX r: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX c: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

SELECT ?s ?author
WHERE {
  ?s rdf:type o:Book .
  ?s o:author ?author .
  ?author ?incategory c:American_atheists .
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that. What about the prefix of `Book`. This causes that you won't get any output (even with proper syntax now), right ?

Comment: @CarleB.Navy Correct

Comment: `o:type` is for sure the wrong relation, it must be `rdf:type`.

Comment: @Sentry No, that's not correct. The prefix for `Book` is correct, but not for the `type` relation

Comment: @AKSW The image says `r:book`, the query says `o:book`, so the prefix in the query is not correct and will return nothing.

Comment: @Sentry Well, I don't care about an image in a book if it's obviously wrong...assuming that the example is taken from DBpedia, it must be `rdf:type`, that's the only reason for the empty results, `o:Book` is correct as the IRIs of the DBpedia classes start with `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` Moreover, it must be `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` without the trailing `s`

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann Can you please fix this: `o:type` -> `rdf:type` and `http://dbpedia.org/resources/` -> `http://dbpedia.org/resource/`

Comment: @AKSW As I've already said, we don't know whether the wrong prefix of `book` is intentional or not, so "obviously wrong" might be exactly what the image or query is aiming for. It is dangerous to just disregard it. If you fix the query, but not the input graph, the result will still be empty.

Comment: Thanks AKSW. Sentry, I think that as the answer is more useful with the IRIs used in DBpedia because the readers will be able to copy and paste it to the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint and see that it brings results.